# jQuery: selecting parent list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the css class of the parent list item when a child list is hovered. For example, I have:

```
<ul class="ipro_menu">
    <li class="menu-first">
        <a href="#">First</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Other A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-second"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, what I'm trying to accomplish is when a `.sub-menu li` element is hovered, change the class of the parent `li` it resides in. In this example, if `li` containing "Other A" or "Other B" is hovered, change the class of the `li.menu-first`.

I've tried:

```
$('.sub-menu li').hover(function(){
    //$(this).closest('.ipro_menu li').addClass('color_a');
    //$(this).parent().addClass('color_a');
    //$(this).parents('li').prev().addClass('color_a');
            // None of the above 3 worked...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
$(this).parents("li").addClass("color_a")
```

That should work. I don't know why you added `.prev()` in your attempt.